# How to call makefile in C++ file in Qt Creator?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, makefile, qt-creator

Enviroment: Ubuntu

I have a C++ project with some classes and with a main function, it has a makefile.
If I use "make" command from terminal I got a proper executable file, my makefile looks like this:

```
g++ -o Output FirstClass.cpp FirstClass.h Anotherfile.cpp -std=c++11
```

In this case the "Output" file

type: shared library (application/x-sharedlib)

size: 300-400 kB

In Qt Creator, I have a project, it contains a model layer, where I call this "make" command, but the result is not what I want.

I am using QProcess like this in model.cpp file, which is part of the Qt project:

```
QProcess process;
QString dir = "../WorkingFolder";
process.setWorkingDirectory(dir);
process.start("make");
process.waitForFinished(-1);
```

In this case I also get result, but the executable file is not the same:

type: Binary (application/octet-stream)

size: 24-25 MB

And when I want to run it from terminal, I got this error message:

```
./Output
bash: ./Output: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

Any idea why QProcess ruin this "make"?

Comment: The environment will be different. Maybe it's passing in parameters that change the way the Makefile works?

Comment: @JarMan I copied my c++ project in the same level as the Qt project, and when use "make" command here from terminal nothing is happening.
What is difference beetwen these two dirs? I just copied my project.

Comment: Compare what really gets run, and maybe figure out if it's the same version of make. It could easily be a different one, and it could call a different compiler.

Comment: I realised something, from terminal, the makefile also make a 24-25 MB executable file, but after a second its reduced to 300-400 kB, but when I do it from Qt the executable file stays 24-25 MB, any idea?

Comment: A greatly reduced executable size is what I would expect to see when debugging information is stripped from the executable.  Does running "strip ./Output" also reduce the file's size?